# Javafx ProgressBar

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

I dont know How to update progress bar for every specified row when downloading to see the progress of my downloading files

Here's a piece of code of the Controller class

```
type here @FXML
    public void btnInsert () throws IOException {


        String urlText = this.downloadUrl.getText().trim(); // Trim to remove leading/trailing spaces
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlText);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        String fileName = Paths.get(url.getFile()).getFileName().toString();
        long fileSize = 0;
        try {
            fileSize = url.openConnection().getContentLengthLong();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        String path = null;
        Url obj = new Url(fileName,fileSize,"waiting",0.1,urlText, path);
        table.getItems().add(obj);



        // Update the progress bar for the newly inserted row
        int newIndex = table.getItems().size() - 1;


        // Update the progress for the specified row
        Url rowItem = table.getItems().get(newIndex);
        rowItem.setProgress(0.1);


        // Refresh the cell to update the progress bar for the given row
        table.refresh();

    }




private void downloadFileAll(String urlText,String downloadPath,int place) throws MalformedURLException {

        if (urlText.isEmpty()) {
            // Alert user if URL is empty
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("URL not found!");
            alert.setHeaderText("Please provide the URL!");
            alert.show();

        }
        URL url = new URL(urlText);
        String fileName = Paths.get(url.getFile()).getFileName().toString();
        String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        System.out.println("File extension: " + extension);

        // Assuming table is your TableView instance
        int rowIndex = 0; // Index of the row containing the ProgressBar
        int columnIndex = 3; // Index of the column containing the ProgressBar



        TableColumn<Url, Double> progressColumn = (TableColumn<Url, Double>) table.getColumns().get(columnIndex); // Replace 'columnIndex' with the actual index of the TableColumn


        DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile(urlText, downloadPath +"\\"+ fileName +"."+extension, this.progressLabel);


        executor.submit(() -> {

            try {
                downloadFile.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        });
    }
```

```
    public void run() {
        try {


            URL url = new URL(this.url);
            InputStream in = url.openStream();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(this.downloadPath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            long fileSize = url.openConnection().getContentLengthLong();
            long totalBytesRead = 0L;

            int bytesRead;
            while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                totalBytesRead += (long)bytesRead;
                long finalTotalBytesRead = totalBytesRead;
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    double progressValue = (double) finalTotalBytesRead / (double)fileSize;
                    this.progress.set(progressValue);
                    String progressText = String.format("%.0f%%", progressValue * 100.0);
                    this.progessLabel.setText(progressText);




                });
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully download");
            Status = "Done";




        } catch (Exception var12) {
            var12.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Download Failed");
        }

    }
```

i tried to get the table of the controller class and update it in the DownloadFile class , but it didnt work for me , i tried this :

```
//    public TableView<Url> table;
//    public void accessTableView(TableView<Url> table) {
//        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
//        try {
//            Parent root = loader.load();
//            HelloController helloController = loader.getController();
//
//            table = helloController.gettable();
//
//            // Now you can work with the TableView
//            // For example, add items to it
////            table.getItems().addAll(new Url(...));
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a table version of one of the solutions from:

- [How to reset progress indicator between tasks in JavaFX2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368793/how-to-reset-progress-indicator-between-tasks-in-javafx2)

Most of the description of how this works is in that solution, so I won't repeat it here.

Differences between this solution and the one in the linked answer:

- This solution uses [TableViews](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) to display data rather than placing labels and progress bars in a VBox.
- A data holder class `FetchInfo` is created for the information displayed in a table row.
- [ObservableLists](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) of `FetchInfo` are used to store the status info on each of the fetched items.
- An [extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687642/callback-and-extractors-for-javafx-observablelist) is used in defining the item lists so that the tables will update when any field in the table is updated.
- A [`ProgressBarTableCell`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/ProgressBarTableCell.html) is used to represent progress for each fetched item.
- The example here is refactored into separate files for each class, which helps readability as more classes are required to support the table based solution.

The example demonstrates fetching data from URLs, but the implementation for downloading a file (at least for the UI, progress monitoring, and task management portions) would be similar.

The example uses plain Java code rather than FXML, but you can adopt it for FXML if you wish.  If you did so, I'd advise keeping the download service code separate from the FXML controller code and to consider using an [MVC approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx).

[image: screenshot]

*FetchInfo.java*

Data model for each table row.

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class FetchInfo {
    private final StringProperty url;
    private final StringProperty statusMessage;
    private final DoubleProperty progress;
    private final StringProperty result;

    public FetchInfo(String url) {
        this.url = new SimpleStringProperty(url);
        statusMessage = new SimpleStringProperty();
        progress = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        result = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url.get();
    }

    public StringProperty urlProperty() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url.set(url);
    }

    public String getStatusMessage() {
        return statusMessage.get();
    }

    public StringProperty statusMessageProperty() {
        return statusMessage;
    }

    public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
        this.statusMessage.set(statusMessage);
    }

    public double getProgress() {
        return progress.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty progressProperty() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(double progress) {
        this.progress.set(progress);
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result.get();
    }

    public StringProperty resultProperty() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result.set(result);
    }
}
```

*FirstLineService.java*

JavaFX service to fetch the first line of text content from a URL.

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

public class FirstLineService extends Service<String> {
    private final StringProperty url = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "url");

    public final void setUrl(String value) {
        url.set(value);
    }

    public final String getUrl() {
        return url.get();
    }

    protected Task<String> createTask() {
        final String _url = getUrl();
        return new Task<>() {
            {
                updateProgress(0, 100);
            }

            protected String call() throws Exception {
                updateMessage(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                URL u = URI.create(_url).toURL();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
                String result = in.readLine();
                in.close();

                // pause just so that it really takes some time to run the task
                // so that parallel execution behaviour can be observed.
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    updateProgress(i, 100);
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                updateProgress(100, 100);

                return result;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

*FirstLineThreadFactory.java*

Factory for creating threads to support the execution of the FirstLineService.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class FirstLineThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private static final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final String type;

    public FirstLineThreadFactory(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable, "LineService-" + poolNumber.getAndIncrement() + "-thread-" + type);
        thread.setDaemon(true);

        return thread;
    }
}
```

*FirstLineFetcher.java*

Uses multiple first line services to fetch the first lines from a list of URLs.

```
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class FirstLineFetcher {
    private final ObservableList<FetchInfo> fetchItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(p ->
            new Observable[] { p.urlProperty(), p.progressProperty(), p.statusMessageProperty(), p.resultProperty() }
    );

    private final DoubleBinding totalProgress;
    private final ObservableList<FirstLineService> services = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public FirstLineFetcher(
            final List<String> URLs,
            final ExecutorService executorService
    ) {
        for (final String url : URLs) {
            final FirstLineService service = new FirstLineService();
            service.setExecutor(executorService);
            service.setUrl(url);

            FetchInfo fetchInfo = new FetchInfo(url);
            fetchItems.add(fetchInfo);

            fetchInfo.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
            fetchInfo.statusMessageProperty().bind(service.messageProperty());

            service.setOnSucceeded(t ->
                    fetchInfo.setResult(service.getValue())
            );

            services.add(service);
        }

        totalProgress = createTotalProgressBinding();
    }

    public void fetch() {
        for (FirstLineService service: services) {
            service.start();
        }
    }

    private DoubleBinding createTotalProgressBinding() {
        final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty[] serviceProgress = new ReadOnlyDoubleProperty[services.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < serviceProgress.length; i++) {
            serviceProgress[i] = services.get(i).progressProperty();
        }

        return Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            double value = 0;

            for (ReadOnlyDoubleProperty readOnlyDoubleProperty : serviceProgress) {
                value += readOnlyDoubleProperty.get();
            }

            value /= serviceProgress.length;

            return value;
        }, serviceProgress);
    }

    public ObservableList<FetchInfo> getFetchItems() {
        return fetchItems;
    }

    public DoubleBinding totalProgressProperty() {
        return totalProgress;
    }
}
```

*LabeledProgressIndicator.java*

A progress indicator with a label.

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class LabeledProgressIndicator extends HBox {
    private final ProgressIndicator progressIndicator;
    public LabeledProgressIndicator(String text) {
        super(10);

        progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setLabelFor(progressIndicator);
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18px;");
        getChildren().addAll(progressIndicator, label);
    }

    public ProgressIndicator getProgressIndicator() {
        return progressIndicator;
    }
}
```

*ServiceUIFactory.java*

Defines the UI for fetching the first line of multiple URLs, displayed in a table with a summary title.

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ProgressBarTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class ServiceUIFactory {
    public Node createUI(String title, FirstLineFetcher fetcher) {
        final VBox layout = new VBox(10);

        LabeledProgressIndicator totalProgress = new LabeledProgressIndicator(title);
        totalProgress.getProgressIndicator().progressProperty().bind(
                fetcher.totalProgressProperty()
        );

        layout.getChildren().addAll(
                totalProgress,
                createFetchTable(fetcher.getFetchItems())
        );

        return layout;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static TableView<FetchInfo> createFetchTable(ObservableList<FetchInfo> items) {
        TableView<FetchInfo> table = new TableView<>(items);
        table.setPrefHeight(150);

        TableColumn<FetchInfo, String> urlColumn = new TableColumn<>("URL");
        urlColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().urlProperty());
        urlColumn.setPrefWidth(200);
        TableColumn<FetchInfo, Double> progressColumn = new TableColumn<>("Progress");
        progressColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().progressProperty().asObject());
        progressColumn.setPrefWidth(100);
        progressColumn.setCellFactory(ProgressBarTableCell.forTableColumn());
        TableColumn<FetchInfo, String> threadNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Status");
        threadNameColumn.setPrefWidth(200);
        threadNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().statusMessageProperty());
        TableColumn<FetchInfo, String> resultColumn = new TableColumn<>("Result");
        resultColumn.setPrefWidth(400);
        resultColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().resultProperty());

        table.getColumns().setAll(
                urlColumn, progressColumn, threadNameColumn, resultColumn
        );

        return table;
    }
}
```

*ServiceTableApp.java*

An application that fetches data from URLs and displays status and results in tables.  Both parallel and sequential fetching of data are demonstrated.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ServiceTableApp extends Application {
    private static final List<String> URLs = List.of(
            "https://www.google.com",
            "https://www.yahoo.com",
            "https://www.microsoft.com",
            "https://www.oracle.com"
    );

    private ExecutorService sequentialExecutor;
    private ExecutorService parallelExecutor;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        sequentialExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
                1,
                new FirstLineThreadFactory("sequential")
        );

        parallelExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
                URLs.size(),
                new FirstLineThreadFactory("parallel")
        );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        parallelExecutor.shutdown();
        parallelExecutor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        sequentialExecutor.shutdown();
        sequentialExecutor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        ServiceUIFactory uiFactory = new ServiceUIFactory();

        FirstLineFetcher parallelFetcher = new FirstLineFetcher(URLs, parallelExecutor);
        FirstLineFetcher sequentialFetcher = new FirstLineFetcher(URLs, sequentialExecutor);

        layout.getChildren().addAll(
                uiFactory.createUI("Parallel Execution", parallelFetcher),
                new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL),
                uiFactory.createUI("Sequential Execution", sequentialFetcher)
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();

        parallelFetcher.fetch();
        sequentialFetcher.fetch();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```